# Help me understand this sentence about film

Tags: translation, meaning

I have a problem understanding this sentence.

> ヒットした映画の続編・続々編が制作されるのも、単に興業収益があがるというだけではなく、2時間程度の映画ではあがるきれないものが多すぎて、その部分を埋めてほしいという観客の要望も背景の一つになっています。

From my understanding the first part:

> ヒットした映画の続編・続々編が制作されるのも、単に興業収益があがるというだけではなく、

Means something like:

> Sequels of popular movies are not only produced to increase the profit,

---

For the next part:

> 2時間程度の映画ではあがるきれないものが多すぎて、

does it mean?

> movies with a 2 hour format　missing a lot(because it is to much)

---

and then the next part is also tricky

> その部分を埋めてほしいという観客の要望も背景の一つになっています。

i came up with something like:

> the desire of the viewers to fill this gap is becoming one with...

but i have the feeling that i get it totally wrong after the second comma starting with 2時間程度...

Comment: The construction あがるきれない looks fishy to me. Can you double check that you transcribed that right?

Comment: Yes i'm sorry there is  error, exactly that part was also a bit fishy for me, but for some reason i hadn't checked the original...
so its not あがるきれない. It is egaku 描ききれない. Now it makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my mind, the sentence is ill-structured on several accounts.

First, 「あがるきれない」should definitely be 「あがりきれない」, but even then its meaning is unclear in this context, to the point of constituting a wrong word choice.

Nevertheless, it can be fairly reasonably inferred that the part「2時間程度の映画ではあがりきれないものが多すぎて」is saying something about **the 2-hour movie leaving many aspects of the story unexplained or untouched.** (「...きれない」means some kind of "incompleteness". )

> ...その部分を埋めてほしいという観客の要望も背景の一つになっています

This part should translate into:

> "...the demand from the audience for 'filling in those missing parts' is one of the reasons (for making sequels)"

with 「背景(background)」being used synoymously with「理由(reason)」.

Overall, a slightly better version of the passage might read something like:

> 「ヒットした映画の続編・続々編を制作するのは、単に興業収益をあげるためだけではありません。2時間程度の映画ではカバーできない箇所も多く、その部分を埋めてほしいという観客の要望も背景の一つになっています。」

Comment: I checked the original again its not あがるきれない. 
It is egaku... 描ききれない.

Comment: Yep, that figures!